# Java Cut Links from shoutcast stream url

Tags: java, string

the string

[playlist]numberofentries=2File1=http://66.162.107.142/cpr1_K128OV.oggTitle1=KCFR NewsLength1=-1File2=http://66.162.107.141:8000/cpr1_K128OV.oggTitle2=KCFR News BackupLength2=-1Version=2

i wanna cut all of the links in this file, how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following class

```
package regexpso;

import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(http:.*?.ogg)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("[playlist]numberofentries=2File1=http://66.162.107.142/cpr1_K128OV.oggTitle1=KCFR NewsLength1=-1File2=http://66.162.107.141:8000/cpr1_K128OV.oggTitle2=KCFR News BackupLength2=-1Version=2");

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

prints

> http://66.162.107.142/cpr1_K128OV.ogg
>   http://66.162.107.141:8000/cpr1_K128OV.ogg

as result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to find and replace the URLs.  Be aware this sort of thing is fraught with peril.  Post an example of what you want the end result to look like for a better answer.  Are all the URLs IP addresses?